# Matlab compiled .exe cannot run with task scheduler but can run with double-click

Tags: windows, matlab, scheduled-tasks, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I have a matlab compiled .exe file, it can run well with double-click, but when run with task scheduler, the following error pops out:

[image]

while actually I have installed the 7.17 of MCR, otherwise it will not run with double click. Anyone can help with this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: what user are you running it as with Task Scheduler?

Comment: @Amro But I have already set the path in command line.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser I use "administrator" by clicking the box "Run this program as an administrator" in the .exe properties.

Comment: @Amro Yes, I did this in command line: set path=C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v717\runtime\win32 , where the dlls are located, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Amro Thanks! After I logged off, and set the path, it can work!

Comment: @JiahuiGuo: I've collected my previous comments as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the MCR installation folder on the PATH environment variable. See [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) for instructions how (you might need to log off/on for it to take effect).

Note that if you are using the SET command in the command prompt, changes made are not permanent, and they would apply to the current CMD prompt only and remain only until the command prompt is closed.